# Power law regression in pymc3

Tags: python, statistics, pymc3

I appear to keep running into problems with pymc3:

Here I'm trying to fit a power law to some data. Namely I'm trying to fit a power law to some data which can go negative due to measurement uncertainty.

Basically I'm fitting a straight line to the logged quantities (logy = mlogx + c) but taking advantage of a power law to use the negative values as well. (y = x**m * 10**c). This  all goes very well until I introduce the measurement uncertainties on z at which point the variational advi flips out and the likelihood doesn't change when sampling. It appears not to matter whether there are no negative zs it just won't fit!

Here is a completely runnable example:

*a little side note: I'm fitting to a ratio of measurements rather than a single measurement. So there is `R = x / y`). Therefore, the equation of fit is `R = 10**intercept * z**gradient`

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from theano.tensor.basic import log10
import pymc3 as pm

# fit_data = pd.read_csv('data.csv').set_index('id').head(10)

# equation to fit: log10(ratio) = log10(1+z)*m + c
# some data is negative (unphysical logs) so to tak advantage of all data: ratio = 10**c * (1+z)**m
equation = lambda z, m, c: (10**c) * ((1+z)**m)

N = 20
C, M = 1, 0
true_z = np.linspace(0, 1, N)
true_ratio = equation(true_z, M, C)

noisy_ratio = np.random.normal(true_ratio, 0.5)
noisy_x = np.random.normal(5, 0.1, N)
noisy_y = noisy_x / noisy_ratio
noisy_z = np.random.normal(true_z, 0.001)

xerr = np.ones(N) * 0.5
yerr = np.ones_like(xerr) * 0.05
zerr = np.ones_like(xerr) * 0.1

fit_data = pd.DataFrame({'x': noisy_x, 'y': noisy_y, 'z': noisy_z, 'xerr': xerr, 'yerr': yerr, 'zerr':zerr})

def plot_data():
    ratio = fit_data.x / fit_data.y
    ratio_err = ratio * np.sqrt((fit_data.xerr / fit_data.x)**2. + (fit_data.yerr / fit_data.y)**2.)
    print 0.434 * fit_data.zerr / fit_data.z
    plt.errorbar(np.log10(fit_data.z+1), np.log10(ratio), 0.434 * ratio_err/ratio, 0.434 * fit_data.zerr / (1+fit_data.z), fmt='.')
    _z = np.linspace(plt.xlim()[0], plt.xlim()[1], 1000)
    plt.plot(_z, np.log10(equation(_z, M, C)))

with pm.Model() as normal_thin_sloped:
    intercept = pm.Normal('intercept', 1.5, sd=20)
    gradient = pm.Normal('gradient', 0, sd=20)
    A = 10**intercept
    epsilon = pm.HalfCauchy('epsilon', 5)

    _ratios = (fit_data.x / fit_data.y)
    _ratio_errs = _ratios * np.sqrt((fit_data.xerr / fit_data.x)**2. + (fit_data.yerr / fit_data.y)**2.)#

    R = pm.Normal('ratio', mu=_ratios.values, sd=_ratio_errs.values, shape=len(fit_data))

    Z = pm.Normal('z', mu=fit_data.z.values, sd=fit_data.zerr.values, shape=len(fit_data))
    likelihood = pm.Normal('likelihood', mu=A * ((1 + fit_data.z.values) ** gradient), sd=epsilon, observed=R)  # this works really well!
    # likelihood = pm.Normal('likelihood', mu=A * ((1 + Z) ** gradient), sd=epsilon, observed=R)  # this fails really badly!

    mu, sds, elbo = pm.variational.advi(n=20000)
    step = pm.NUTS(scaling=normal_thin_sloped.dict_to_array(sds), is_cov=True)
    trace = pm.sample(1000, step=step, start=mu, progressbar=True)

    pm.traceplot(trace, varnames=['gradient', 'intercept', 'z'])

    plt.figure()
    plot_data()
    _x = np.linspace(*plt.xlim())
    plt.plot(_x, np.median(trace['intercept']) + (_x*np.median(trace['gradient'])))
    plt.show()
```

Thanks